# Cross region replication EC2 machines

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

1.Is it possible to have replication between master postgresql in one AWS region and slave in another AWS region?.

Basically we are looking for a Disaster recovery set up(in cross region). We prefer to use postgresql in EC2 over RDS since we want better control over configurations.

2.Basically we are planning to migrate a three tier architecture application with db hosted in separate machines to AWS EC2.

Currently in our on-premise design we have replication setup( for database ) to another similar set of vms in datacenter set up in another region.?

Can we have the same DR design with EC2 instances in cross region?

Comment: If you don't use RDS, you have to setup everything by yourself. So off course its possible, but you have to manage it all.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.My research shows it is possible but we may need to use VPC peering for cross region network connectivity.